# QGIS Slope analysis thinks elevation unit is degrees making all slopes 90 degrees or 0 degrees

Tags: qgis, slope

When i run my slope analysis the output has only two values: 0 and close to 90 degrees. The only way I have found to solve this is using a z factor of 1/111,120 which is the conversion of degrees to meters. This makes me think that the program is using meters for linear units and degrees as vertical units. I have tried to reproject my DEM to UTM and some other CRS's to try and change this with no luck.

Can anybody tell me how to change my vertical units to meters in my DEM or if my diagnosis is wrong tell me what my problem is?
[image][image]

Comment: Some more input on your DEM (source, units & values, screenshot) and your settings when running the slope analysis would be helpful.

Comment: Are the above helpful?

Comment: The first one isn't. Can you provide either a downloadlink to the data, or a small excerpt of the DEM?

Comment: https://webservices.maps.canada.ca/fmedatadownload/results/FME_5644441C_1570456314654_8480.zip

Comment: The DEM is originally in EPSG 4140, which is based on degree. Once you reproject the DEM to 2962, the slope-analysis works fine.

Comment: I've tried to reproject it, but it seems not to be working for me. I am using the Raster>Projections>Warp tool. Is that an incorrect way to reproject?

Comment: Depends on the CRS you are setting.

Comment: I would like to use EPSG 32182 or 2962

Comment: And what happens when you do so?

Comment: It loads a new layer using whichever CRS I chose, but the slope analysis still has the same problem

Comment: Have you made sure you run the slope analysis on the reprojected layer? Because for me it works. Which QGIS are you using?

Comment: 3.8.3. I was using 3.4 but upgraded yesterday after I kept running into this problem. I just redownloaded the data and tried the same steps with the fresh DEM and it worked! Thank you for helping! I have no idea what was different this time though